# Scrapy is skipping over links

Tags: python, scrapy

This is the URL https://www.arabam.com/ikinci-el/otomobil?page=14

I am looping through URLs. It processes the ad if the year is greater than 2010. This is my code

```
class Myspider(SitemapSpider):
    name = 'spidername'

    custom_settings = {'FEED_FORMAT':'csv','FEED_URI': "arabam_"+str(datetime.today().strftime('%d%m%y'))+'.csv'}
    def start_requests(self):
        urls = ['https://www.arabam.com/ikinci-el/otomobil?page=14']
        # urls = ['https://www.arabam.com/ikinci-el/otomobil?page=' + str(i) for i in range(1, 50)]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)
    def parse(self,response):


            for td in response.xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[6]/div[4]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[4]/div/a/@href").extract():
                checks = str(td.split("/")[3]).split("-")

                for items in checks:
                    if items.isdigit():

                        if int(items) > 2010:

                            url = "https://www.arabam.com/"+ td
                            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_dir_contents)
```

There are around 10 ads on this page that are greater than 2010. However, Scrapy only saved around 3 pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your xpath selection is wrong.

Currently your `td` is an element of a list that contains all links and looks something like this:
['/ilan/sahibinden-satilik-peugeot-407-1-6-hdi-millesim/111-bin-km-de-efsane-d-segment/14278421',
'/ilan/galeriden-satilik-seat-le
on-1-6-tdi-style/simsek-ten-2016-leon-cam-tavan-dsg-led-katlanir-ayna/13804838',
 '/ilan/galeriden-satilik-skoda-favorit-135-lx/aci
ll-satilik-firsat-araci/13027823',
...]

Then you split it by a slash, get element no. 3 and again split it by a dash, which returns something like that for each td:
['111', 'bin', 'km', 'de', 'efsane', 'd', 'segment']
['simsek', 'ten', '2016', 'leon', 'cam', 'tavan', 'dsg', 'led', 'katlanir', 'ayna']
['acill', 'satilik', 'firsat', 'araci']

As you see in this example, your code would only work for the second link, as it contains the year you are looking for (2016 > 2010). The other links just don't contain the year and so your code does not work for them. You should instead get the year-information from the table, not from the link.

I recommend using scrapy shell for finding the correct selector, because you can interactively test your xpath or css selections and see exactly what your result would look like ([see this official example](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/shell.html#example-of-shell-session)).

The following parse-definition should work for you:

```py
    def parse(self, response):
        rows = response.css('.listing-list-item') # extract all rows
        for row in rows:
            year = row.css('td:nth-child(4) a::text').extract_first() # extract year from every row
            if int(year) > 2010:
                suburl = row.css('td:nth-child(4) a::attr(href)').extract_first()
                url = "https://www.arabam.com" + suburl # create new url
                yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_dir_contents) # request new url
```

The code first gets each row of the table, then gets the year for the row and if this year is > 2010 it create the new url and requests it.
This code will work under assumption that you defined your parse_dir_contents-method somewhere.